# How can I get the text length value after truncating through css properties in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string-length, content-length, truncated

Text:
`Value soooo soooo lognnng Value soooo soooo lognnng Value soooo soooo lognnng Value` 
Normal length: 83

Text After Truncate:

`Value soooo soooo lognnng...`

Truncate length: 28

Question:
How to get the text length after truncated?

I tried get length by dom.

But the length is always full.
How to get the text length after truncated?

```js
const div = document.querySelector('#txt')
console.log(div.innerText.length)
```

```html
<div id="txt" style="font-size: 0.9em; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
  Value soooo soooo lognnng Value soooo soooo lognnng Value soooo soooo lognnng Value soooo soooo
</div>
```

Comment: How are you truncating the string? Does it appear like that in the UI? You need to discover how the truncating happens and use that in your calculation.

Comment: your div is not even truncated

Answer (score 0):

Well that's pretty easy to do let's say you're using a function called `truncateMyString` to truncate your string you'll need to do the following:

```js
const string = 'very long string'
const truncatedString = truncateMyString(string);
console.log(`the rest of my truncated string length is: ${string.length - truncatedString.length}`);
```

and that's it, *Please let me know if you do not understand something in the code above*.

Comment: Ok, but i truncate by CSS:

`<div id="txt" style="font-size: 0.9em; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
  Value soooo soooo lognnng Value soooo soooo lognnng Value soooo soooo lognnng Value soooo soooo
</div>`


And i need the value length truncated.